# Is there a 'distributional antiderivative'?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose I have a distribution $F$ which I know on the derivative of an arbitrary test function. That is, I know $F(\phi')$ for all $\phi ∈ \mathcal{D}(ℝ)$. I also know that $F(\phi') = -F'(\phi)$. I *want*, however, to know $F(\phi)$. Is there a 'distributional antiderivative' that immediately tells me what this should be? If not, is it possible for such $F'$ that are induced by simpler, specific functions? (e.g. polynomials)

For $\Phi(x) := ∫\phi(x)dx$, simply putting $F(\phi) = -F'(\Phi)$ seems a little dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists $\psi\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $\phi=\psi'$ then we can just set $F(\phi) = -F'(\psi).$

But this is in general not the case. It is true precisely when $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx=0.$ Now fix $\rho\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x)\,dx=1$ and given $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ set $\tilde\phi=\phi-(\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx) \, \rho.$ Then $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\phi(x)\,dx=0$ so we can apply the first paragraph on $\tilde\phi.$ Now we note that $F\left((\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx)\rho\right) = F(\rho)(\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx)$ is just some constant $F(\rho)$ times the constant distribution $\phi\mapsto\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx$ acting on $\phi.$

Thus, we can set $F(\phi) = F(\tilde\phi) + F(\rho)(\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx).$

Comment: Do you mean "Then $∫_{-∞}^∞ \tilde{\phi}(x)dx = 0$ so we can apply..."?

Comment: I was actually hoping that this would prove the following: if $(∃ p_{k-1} ∈ ℂ[x]_{k-1})(F'(\phi) = ∫p_{k-1}(x)\phi(x)dx)$ then $(∃ p_k ∈ ℂ[x]_k)(F(\phi) = ∫p_k(x)\phi(x)dx)$.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman. Yes, it should be $\tilde\phi.$ I have fixed that.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman. If $F'$ is given by the polynomial $p,$ then $F$ is given by a polynomial $q$ such that $q'=p.$

Comment: And does this provide a way to go from $′()=∫_{−1}()()$ for a polynomial of $p_{k-1}$ degree at most $k-2$ to $()=∫_()()$ for a polynomial $p_k$ of degree at most $k-1$?

Comment: Just let $p_k$ be any of the ordinary primitive functions (polynomials) of $p_{k-1}.$ For example, if $F'(\phi) = \int (3x^2 + 2x - 7) \phi(x) \, dx$ then you can take $F(\phi) = -\int (x^3 + x^2 - 7x + C) \phi(x) \, dx$ for any value of $C.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124148/discussion-between-jos-van-nieuwman-and-md2perpe).